# Typical norm on polynomial vector spaces

Tags: polynomials, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

What is the most common or intuitive way to define a norm on a vector space of polynomials? I tried searching it, but all the questions seem to be "would this work as a norm?" type.

Comment: [Polynomial norm](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolynomialNorm.html) found using Google search.

Comment: Can say explicitly what the space of polynomials you are interested is? A reasonable answer requires more information for example is the space finite or infinite dimensional? Are the polynomials defined over a bounded set?

Comment: You introduce a norm on a vector space in order to study some ideas that  matter to you at the time. There is no general "most common or intuitive" norm.

Comment: I was interested in inf dimension space of polynomials, and linear maps on them. I also saw the link @mathcounterexamples.net posted but that looked more complicated than I expected since vector spaces of polynomials are introduced in low level algebra classes, but thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous norms you could put on a space of polynomials (I'll assume real polynomials, but complex polynomials are almost the same). As Ethan Bolker said, which you want depends on what you are interested in. Here are a few of the more common ones. They can be sorted into those that treat the polynomial as a function, and those that treat it as its sequence of coefficients. (There are norms that do neither, but the most common ones fall into one camp or the other.)

**Function Norms:**

Many function norms are problematic when directly applied to polynomials because polynomials are unbounded, leading to the polynomial having an infinite norm. The most common cures for this are either to limit the polynomial domain to some bounded set, or to introduce a weighting to the norm that ameliorates the polynomial growth.

For example:

- Choose some interval $[a,b]$ (usually $[0,1]$ or $[-1,1]$) and

  - Define the inner product $\langle P, Q\rangle = \int_a^b P(x)Q(x)\, dx$. This induces the norm $\|P\|_2 = \sqrt{\langle P, P\rangle}$. This is called a "Euclidean" or "$L_2$" norm.
  - Define the "uniform" norm $\|P\|_\infty = \max \{|P(x)| : x \in [a,b]\}$
- Choose some weighting function such as $w(x) = e^{-x^2}$ that goes to $0$ faster than polynomials go to $\infty$ and

  - Define the $L_2$ inner product $\langle P, Q\rangle = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} w(x)P(x)Q(x)\, dx$, with its induced norm.
  - Define the uniform norm $\|P\|_\infty = \max \{|w(x)P(x)| : x \in [a,b]\}$.

**Sequence Norms:**

These identify the polynomial $P(x) = p_0 + p_1x+p_2x^2 + \dots + p_nx^n$ for some $n$ with the finite sequence $(p_0, p_1, \dots, p_n)$. So as not to have to worry about the degree of the polynomial/length of the sequence, we can extend the sequence to an infinite one by setting $p_k = 0$ for all $k > n$.

The two most common norms are very similar to the function norms above:

- Define the inner product $\langle P, Q\rangle = \sum_{k=0}^\infty p_kq_k$, which is only a finite sum because both sequences are eventually $0$. Once again, this induces the norm $\|P\|_2 = \sqrt{\langle P, P\rangle}$. This is called the $l_2$ norm on sequences (upper case $L$ for functions, lower case $l$ for sequences).
- Define the uniform norm $\|P\|_\infty = \max\{|p_k| : k \in \Bbb N\}$.

As before, one could take some fixed weighting sequence $(w_k)_{k \in \Bbb N}$ and define $\langle P, Q\rangle = \sum_{k=0}^\infty w_kp_kq_k$ or $\|P\|_\infty = \max\{|w_kp_k| : k \in \Bbb N\}$ instead. But unlike with the function norms, this isn't necessary.

Comment: thank you, this was very helpful!